# In R, Is there a way to for loop over a function and bind all output into 1 dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a function defined as:

```
Bestideas <- function(x) {
  Top_five = subset(Masterall, Masterall$Name == x) %>% slice(1:5)
  return(as.data.frame(Top_five))
}
```

I would then like a dataframe containing the "Bestideas" output for every name in a given list, so I do the following: 1. Create an empty dataframe. 2. Create for loop til bind output of every name in my function:

```
bestideas_collection = data.frame()

for (i in MYLISTOFNAMES){
    bind_rows(bestideas_collection, Bestideas(i))
  }
```

However, I keep getting the error "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

(Not inserted twice, this is the actual error message)

Can anyone help me if this is even possible?, and if so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your example should work, you forget to assign it in your loop:

```
bestideas_collection = data.frame()

for (i in MYLISTOFNAMES){
    bestideas_collection  <- bind_rows(bestideas_collection, Bestideas(i))
  }
```

Please, give an example when you ask a question. I give one:

```
Masterall <- data.frame(Name = rep(LETTERS[1:5],each = 10),value = rnorm(50))
MYLISTOFNAMES <- c("A","B")
```

Best use is to generate a list of data.frame, that you can actually bind with `bind_rows` (or `do.call(rbind, yourlist)` in base R, or `rbindlist` in `data.table`):

```
lapply(MYLISTOFNAMES,Bestideas) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

So you don't have to create an empty data.frame that you update in a loop. You can use `map` from `purr` also:

```
purrr::map(MYLISTOFNAMES,Bestideas) %>%
  bind_rows()


   Name       value
1     A  1.19390555
2     A  1.20447637
3     A -0.78496237
4     A  0.27154501
5     A -0.02922748
6     B -0.47460937
7     B -2.09716169
8     B  0.06161554
9     B  1.55524055
10    B  0.75727887
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have tried to fix it by assigning it in my loop as suggested, which of course makes great sense - so once again, thank you for spotting. 

However, it seems as if the loop runs only once (As the variable bestideas_collection only holds only 5 values), and then it gives me the same error message "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

This is even when I try the other rmethods you suggested like the lapply function.  Could it be something with my dataframe?

Comment: ... And its seems that the 5 values that it holds are from distinct names ( Meaning that it is not the top 5 ideas from the same name, but 5 single ideas from 5 different names )  Which I fin a bit odd, because that must mean that the loop runs over at least 5 of the items in the data.frame

Comment: However, if I do it manually like this:

`holder <- Bestideas("NAME1")
bestideas_collection <- bind_rows(bestideas_collection,holder)`

It works just as intended. I have 100 Names - so doing it manually for every single one is a bit hard

Comment: If i change my slicer to 10 in the function, the for loop will save 1 variable from 10 different names, instead of 10 variables from each individual name. I hope this helps of some sort

Comment: you will have to give an actual example reproducing your error. Maybe just doing so you will solve the problem yourself. I can't easily figure out what is your problem if I do not have an example to test my/your code